# Capturing JSON data off a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I know this is somewhat general, but say we have a server that spits out JSON something like
`server.com/spit.ashx?data&moredata`

And I can get a long JSON string when I visit this something like

```
  { data1: 23523, data2: 25235 } ...
```

And when I try to access this same data using the Jquery

```
$.ajax {
  type: 'GET'
  url: 'server.com/spit.ashx'
  etc..
}
```

it hangs forever.

Is this generally a security feature of the site, or am I not implementing it the right way?

Comment: Is the server on a different domain than the domain the JavaScript is running on?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Yes, thank you, but I had some success using JSONP to work around this. Is this a valid solution?

Comment: use jsonp if it's on another domain, or use cors, or use getJSON

Comment: JSONP is completely valid if the server supports it and you only need to do GET requests.

Comment: Problem is I was able to retrieve the data with JSONP, but for some reason in never makes it's way into the data callback function.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this is because you normally can't make AJAX queries cross-domain. To change this, have the server that serves the JSON set the header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

(Or just add the domain you're requesting from to Access-Control-Allow-Origin.)

How this is done depends on the server type/backend code used on the server serving the JSON.